# PHP variables crossing require_once and functions

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

I have 2 php files.

index.php:

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    require_once('temp.php');
    temp();
    echo $counter;
?>
```

temp.php:

```
<?php
    function temp() {
            tempHelper();
    }
    function tempHelper() {
            $counter++;
    }
?>
```

I want to print 1 not 0.
I tried to set $counter as global variable without success.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tempHelper` function is incrementing a local `$counter` variable, not the global one. You have to either pass the variable in by reference through both functions, or use the global variable:

```
function tempHelper() {
  global $counter;
  $counter++;
}
```

Note that dependence on global variables likely indicates a design flaw in your application.

Comment: Faster than me :) Here is a link http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: There is not way to set in the initalization of $counter to make him global?

Comment: In PHP, there is no way to make user defined [super globals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). If you are wanting to do this though, reconsider your application design.

Comment: I hope you do not ignore all the people advising you *not to do this*. You shouldn't be using global variables unless you fully understand why they are bad and make a conscious decision to use them anyways.

Comment: Why no to use it? Why that are bad thing?

Comment: They lead to unmaintainable code. They're a violation of encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using global variables. Using a class for your counter would probably be better.

```
class Counter {
    public $counter;

    public function __construct($initial=0) {
        $this->counter = $initial;
    }

    public function increment() {
        $this->counter++;
    }

}
```

---

Or just use a variable without a function. Your function seems redundant, since it would be just as easy to type `$counter++` than it would the function name.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this should work:

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;

    function temp() {
            // global $counter; [edited, no need for that line]
            tempHelper();
    }
    function tempHelper() {
            global $counter;
            $counter++;
    }

    temp();
    echo $counter;
?>
```

Or you can pass the variable as an argument or return new value from that function.

More info at http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=1602.0

Comment: There is no reason to declare `global $counter` inside `temp`, which doesn't use it.

Comment: I just realized it now. Thanks.

Comment: The temp function seems redundant.